# jQuery UI Progress bar theme not working?

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I downloaded jQuery UI the progressbar component so that I can add a progress bar to my page.  I wanted a certain theme that the site allows you to download the component http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/ with a theme.  I chose the "start" theme (blueish with a wave).

It downloaded an example file along with a css folder with all the images inside of the css folder.  When I run the example I see the correct progress bar:

[image]

So I look at the html and it has the following for this example page:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/start/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui 1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
```

So what I did was add all these folders js, css to my project and add a progress bar to my page:

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

Now when I run it in my project and run my project my progress bar looks to be a default orange with no theme, like so:

[image]

Is there somewhere / something else I am missing that doesn't correctly theme this progress bar, I did what I think exactly what the example does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

along with CSS, you should get the images, which you need to copy to your images folder.

Comment: I do have the images, they are stored right within the css folder...Try it out yourself.  If you download the theme 'Start' it comes with a folder CSS with a subfolder start and within that subfolder is a folder called images with all the images.  This is not the problem.  The example page makes no reference to this, as I think the CSS references the css->start->images folder, which I already have...

Comment: Can you use Firebug or Chrome Dev tools or IE Dev tool-bar to see if the images are loaded in run-time